# Xcode interface Builder doesn't give me option where to put reuse identifier for a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've created a new xib by New File->View. So, I put a name for my class which is a child of UITableViewCell.

[image]

But in the next inlay there is no option of where to put in a reuse identifier.

[image]

I tried this several times and it's all the same. Could anyone suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: try to create new file i think you missing some

Comment: i think you have not cell looking like UIView

Answer (score 2):

[image]

create UITableViewCell like this bcs you take the uiview and extend the tableviewcell class

see second image you have UIView not cell

[image]

Comment: So, that's exactly what's on my screenshots, isn't it?

Comment: @Vlad Alexeev in xib you have Uiview Not tableviewcell.remove extend class than check

Comment: I tried both GameResultCell and UITableViewCell in a class window - doesn't change

Comment: @Vlad Alexeev  delete your existing cell or view and take new tableviewcell and than extend your class.you can see your cell reuseidentifier

Comment: yes, that's work. But why couldn't I create a table view cell in a first place. Weird.

Comment: @Vlad Alexeev when you create cell class than you checkmark xib option or not?

Comment: @Vlad Alexeev i think you pick uiview instead of uitableviewcell.and first time uiview take the cell class extend

Comment: but my class is extending uitableviewcell - it's on a screenshot

Comment: remove your extending class than send me screenshot

Comment: @Vlad Alexeev if your problem is solved than pls accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you selected something else, Not TableViewCell

Please see below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have want to set Reuse Identifier for cell, then must use cocoatuch file with xib select see below image. You can't create seperate xib, coz xib file have no any property like Reuse identifier.

[image]

Comment: isn't that what I'm clicking on the screenshot?

Comment: Click on Xib file and then click on Attribute Inspector

Comment: Make sure ResultTableViewCell is the subclass of UITableView cell. And you assign ResultTableViewCell class name to Xib

Comment: it is all actually on the screenshot